# R RStudio change system date time language

Tags: r, datetime, rstudio, weekday

When I extract weekdays(date) from some date vector I get weekdays in language other than English. Here is my setting:

```
> Sys.getlocale()
[1] "LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=he_IL.UTF-8;LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8;LC_MONETARY=he_IL.UTF-8;LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8;LC_PAPER=he_IL.UTF-8;LC_NAME=C;LC_ADDRESS=C;LC_TELEPHONE=C;LC_MEASUREMENT=he_IL.UTF-8;LC_IDENTIFICATION=C"
```

when I try to set the time back to English:

```
Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "English")
```

I get error message:

```
Warning message:
In Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "English") :
  OS reports request to set locale to "English" cannot be honored
```

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

The system locale might need administrator privileges. Hence you might not be having rights to change them. You can try to run R as administrator and give it a shot.

Comment: have any idea how to do that?